# NGINX reverse proxy WebSockets with JWT auth no Access-Control-Allow-Origin header

Tags: websocket, lua, jwt, nginx-reverse-proxy, openresty

My goal is to use `NGINX` proxy server to terminate a `wss` connection from the frontend and establish a `ws` connection to my backend. I also need to authenticate the client using `JWT` tokens which I am successfully issuing and passing via `Cookie` to the `NGINX` proxy.

I am using the `nginx-jwt` package (https://github.com/auth0/nginx-jwt) with the `OpenResty` distribution of `NGINX`. My `nginx.conf` file looks like this:

`env JWT_SECRET;
env JWT_SECRET_IS_BASE64_ENCODED;
http {
    ...
    lua_package_path "usr/local/openresty/nginx-jwt;;";
    map $http_upgrade $connection_upgrade {
        default upgrade;
        '' close;
    }
    upstream appserver {
        server [server ip]:[port];
    }
    server {
        server_name api.[domain].org;
        listen 443 ssl;
        listen 80;
        ssl on;
        ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/api.[domain].org/fullchain.pem;
        ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/dev.[domain].org/privkey.pem;
        locaiton /connect {
            access_by_lua_block {
                local jwt = require("nginx-jwt")
                jwt.auth()
            }
            proxy_pass http://appserver$uri;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection $connection_upgrade;
            add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://[domain].org;
        }
    }
}`

When I try to hit `[domain].org/connect/[sockjs stuff]` from my browser I get the error:

`Failed to load https://api.[domain].org/connect/info?t=1531334401388: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'https://[domain].org' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 500.`

The weird part is that when I comment out the `access_by_lua_block{}` I get a 200 response, but with the error:

`Failed to load https://api.[domain].org/connect/info?t=1531336691243: The 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header contains multiple values 'https://[domain].org, https://[same domain].org', but only one is allowed. Origin 'https://[domain].org' is therefore not allowed access.`

and no websocket connection is established.

But if I comment out both the `access_by_lua_block{}` and `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin https://[domain].org;` I am able to successfully establish a websocket connection to the backend.

I have been banging my head off the wall over this for days. Please help.

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED: The relative path on my `lua_package_path` was pointing to a directory rather than the actual `*.lua` files. I changed the path to `/usr/local/openresty/nginx-jwt/?.lua;/usr/local/openresty/nginx-jwt/lib/?.lua;;`.

I also removed the `add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin` from the `nginx.conf` because I handle that on the backend as well, so I was getting an error about multiple entries for the `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` header.

Apparently the CORS error being thrown on the browser was just a result of the browser not being able to hit a valid endpoint because of the error in the code.